# How to configure DNS servers manually on Ubuntu server via bash?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, dhcp

- I still want to use DHCP to obtain IP4 and IP6 addresses.
- DHCP delivers DNS servers
- I want that the DNS servers from DHCP are ignored and two servers I specify manually are used instead.
- Must be done on a headless server (no GUI) via Bash.
- ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64, standard minimal installation + sshd

How is this configured correctly?

How to verify that the configuration works as expected?

/etc/network/interfaces is:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto em1
iface em1 inet dhcp
```

resolvconf is installed.

Comment: Can you use `vi` to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add your own DNS server entries?

Comment: Yes, I could do that. What should I put there? How does it interact with resolv.conf?

Comment: Add `dns-nameservers <your DNS server IPs>` to the end of your `interfaces` file and reboot the server... this should add the required DNS servers to the network config...

Comment: There is some documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html, but it doesn't help me (no enough details about how to write the "stanza"s and what effect they have).

Comment: Can you expand on the last comment? You shouldn't need to put `<` and `>` - this was my way of saying "this is where you type your DNS server IPs". For example: `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` to add Google's primary and secondary DNS addresses.

Comment: @Big Chris: sorry, didn't see your comment when I wrote mine.

Comment: @Big Chris: Your proposal seems not to work. I did the change. The content of resolv.conf did not change. I did ifdown em1: resolv.conf has no more DNS servers. I did ifup em1: resolv.conf gets again DNS from DHCP, not those configured in interfaces.

Comment: Accidentally clicked to start a chat conversation... sorry! This answer may help with additional options to try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf

Comment: I tried to use /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf: prepend domain-name-servers, but it doesn't work. "Adding" name server entries is not what I want. The interfaces approach possibly only works with "static" and not with "dhcp".

Comment: Try using `supersede domain-name-servers` rather than `prepend` - as seen http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146463/specifying-dns-settings-to-override-those-of-dhcp

Comment: Both supersede and prepend do not work. /etc/resolv.conf still has the two servers from DHCP after a reboot.

Comment: Have a read of this (https://raam.org/2009/configuring-static-dns-with-dhcp-on-debianubuntu/)... we might be getting the wrong file...

Comment: Thanks, I got an syntax error into resolv.conf, now supersede works!

Comment: I still cannot guess the correct syntax for supersede to add two nameservers. Separated by blank provoces a syntax error.

Comment: separate the two IPs with a comma :) e.g. `supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line

```
supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

to the DHCP client configuration file /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf.

To verify get the names of your network interfaces with ifconfig, shut down the interface(s) with ifdown *ifname* (e.g. ifdown eth0), restart it with ifup *ifname* (e.g. ifup eth0).
After that (or after a reboot) /etc/resolv.conf should contain the two lines

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Thanks to Big Chris.