# What is the correct syntax for the dhclient.conf supersede statement?

Tags: dhcp

I am using the Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4.

I want to use the supersede statement to override two DNS servers from DHCP.

The corresponding man page section reads:

```
The supersede statement
supersede [ option declaration ] ;
If for some option the client should always use a locally-configured 
value or values rather than whatever is supplied by the server, 
these values can be defined in the supersede statement.
```

I am not able to figure out what the correct syntax for the supersede statement could be for two DNS servers.

Is there a web page with the man page for ISC DHCP Client 4.2.4 that could I link here?

This question is not about configuring DNS servers (which is a concrete example I gave here), but it is about the syntax of the dhclient.conf file, especially about the supersede statement that can be used to override not only DNS servers but also other settings obtained from the DHCP server, for example the IP address itself.

When do you have to use quotes?
How does the grouping with { and } work? Can that be applied to supersede?
At some places commas are used, but I saw examples using a blank as separation of multiple values, too.

What can I use as "option"? Is there a list of available options? Obviously "domain-name-servers" is one of the available options.

It seems that the supersede statement can be used outside or within the context of a single interface configuration block. I suppose outside just applies to every interface?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure DNS servers manually on Ubuntu server via bash?](http://superuser.com/questions/944307/how-to-configure-dns-servers-manually-on-ubuntu-server-via-bash)

Comment: The scope is different, I think. Supersede can be used for more options, it would be nice to understand the syntax of that statement (and possibly the syntax of the whole dhclient.conf file).

Comment: If you were to scroll down the `man` page, you'd see an example.

Comment: I couldn't find an example. What example do you mean?

Comment: If you mean line 398: supersede domain-search "fugue.com", "rc.vix.com", "home.vix.com"; I tried some variations that all didn't work. When have quotes to be used and when not? What about whitespace?

Comment: That's it. Is that not clear enough?

Comment: No. What would you put?

Answer (score 6):

The options you can use are listed in the [`dhcp-options` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcp-options).

There are examples in the [debian network configuration guide](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#DHCP_Client_Configuration):

```
supersede domain-name-servers 12.34.56.78, 12.34.56.79;
```

But it is almost better to use prepend for that pourpose:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 12.34.56.78, 12.34.56.79;
```

Comment: Why is prepend better?

Comment: @71GA With prepend those provided by dhcp work as a fallback

Answer (score 0):

It accepts a wide range of expressions, including executing external commands. [dhcp-eval](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcp-eval) man page lists them.